# Image and block level input on same line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

As shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/F57mK/), I have a Bootstrap media object with a block level text area in it. When the `overflow` property is set to `hidden`, as in Bootstrap by default, it shows just fine (as shown in the top div). But I need to set `overflow` to visible to use [this](http://caseyjhol.github.io/bootstrap-select/) select library, and when I do that, the block level input expands to 100% and jumps to the next line. How can I keep both the image and the textarea on the same line (with the textarea filling the rest of the space), without using `overflow: hidden`? I know how to do it using absolute positioning, but that just brings about even more issues.

Here's the code that works by bootstrap default, but not when I set the overflow to visible.

```
<div class='media' style='border: 1px solid black'>
    <a class='pull-left' href='#'>
        <img class='media-object img-rounded' src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4c13c80ca93c714560cd72e628d93939.jpg?d=identicon&s=64' />
    </a>
    <div class='media-body' style='overflow: visible'>
        <textarea class='input-block-level' style='height:64px' ></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually came up with an easy way of doing it. The semantic web purists out there will hate me, but since they didn't attempt to help me, they don't get an opinion.

```
<div class='media' style='border: 1px solid black'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a class='pull-left' href='#'>
                    <img class='media-object img-rounded' src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4c13c80ca93c714560cd72e628d93939.jpg?d=identicon&s=64' />
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class='media-body' style='overflow: visible'>
                    <textarea class='input-block-level' style='height:64px' ></textarea>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```